# Homomorphic system that allows Hamming distance computation?

Tags: encryption, homomorphic-encryption

How can I work out Hamming distance between two binary vectors securely?
I would like to know how I can apply homomorphic techniques here.

Comment: I'm sure there are papers out there on this. What have you found and why isn't it sufficient?

Comment: Please define "secure". Do you want to outsource this task to an untrusted server and don't want him to learn the vectors or the weight? Do you want to protect against side-channel attacks?

Comment: Yes I want it to be outsourced to an untrusted server and want the vector to remain oblivious.

Comment: If you keep your question vague, the answers will remain vague. Yes, there are protocols that enable a functionality that uses similar terms to the ones that you are using. Now, to obtain useful results, you need to explain what you know, what are your constraints and what you have tried.

Comment: The first intuition makes us to want encrypt the binary vectors using some homomorphic encryption scheme whose the message space is the ring $\mathbb{Z}_2$, since for any $i$, the sum of bits $u_i + v_i$ would give us the hamming distance between $i$-th bits, and then we would just need to accumulate those sums to all $i$ to get the hamming distance between two vectors $u$ and $v$. But the problem is that accumulating them would require arithmetic outside $\mathbb{Z}_2$...

Comment: Have a look at this article "Homomorphic Computation of Edit Distance" by Cheon et.al https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/132.pdf, where authors show how to compute edit distance on encrypted data. Hamming weight is a particular case of edit distance and maybe you can improve their work for this situation.